# arara: Running BibTeX FAILURE

Tags: bibtex, arara

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, and I use Texlive 2014 which includes the Arara arealdy. I get the error "Running BibTeX FAILURE" when I test Arara. The tex file is as following:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\bibliography{test}
\begin{document}
test\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

while the test.bib file is as following:

```
@article{test,
 title={test},
 author={test},
 journal={test},
 year={test}
}
```

I do not find a solution anywhere. Look forward to any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The failure is not related to `arara`, but to the fact that you're loading twice your bibliography database:

```
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\bibliography{test}
```

All you have to do is to remove the line

```
\bibliography{test}
```

which is redundant.

So the MWE

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
test\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

will compile without failure and will give the following output:

[image]