# Arara Error BibMacro

Tags: bibtex, texlive, ubuntu, texworks, arara

I am using arara (on ubuntu 16, TeXLive, TeXWorks), in which I run biblatex (backfalling onto bibtex). In Windows, the same document compiled without error, so I assume it's arara's fault. The error I receive when trying to compile is:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-mla/mla.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.
<to be read again> 
                   4
l.56     {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4
                                              }{#5}{#7}}
?
```

It doesn't matter if I add extra spaces before the bibliography in the MWE I provided, it always says line 56. I looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243785/arara-running-bibtex-failure) question, but I'm only calling my file once (as seen below). Another question (which I cannot find) was with a user-made bibliography-type error, which is not my case. The other questions I have seen do not solve my answer, or I don't understand, but any that do solve it would be appreciated.

> Edit: My version of BiBTeX is 0.99d, which seems to be the newest version, and I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439741/ubuntu-14-04-biblatex) link to install BiBLaTeX and Biber, but it still gives the same error

Here is the MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=mla, citestyle=authoryear-comp, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}

@article{Lagarias,
    author =       "Jeffery C. Lagarias",
    title =        "{Euler's constant: Euler's work and modern developments}",
    journal =      "Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society",
    volume =       "50",
    pages =        "556",
    year =         "2013",
    DOI =          "10.1090/s0273-0979-2013-01423-x"
}

@inbook{Leonhard,
    author    = "Leonhard Euler",
    title     = "{Tentamen novae theoriae musicae ex certissimis harmoniae principiis dilucide expositae}. ({Latin}) [{An illuminating} new theory of music {most exposed} to the principles of harmony]",
    chapter     = "Chapter VII. De Variorum Intervallorum Receptis Appelationibus",
    year      = "1739",
    publisher     = "St Petersburg Academy",
    pages     = "102--112",
    address   = "St Petersburg"
}

@inbook{Stifel,
    author    = "Michael Stifel",
    title     = "{Arithmetica Integra}. ({Latin})[ Integrated Arithmetic]",
    pages     = "8--9",
    year      = "1544",
    publisher     = "Johann Petreium",
    address   = "Nuremburg",
    URL     = "https://books.google.com/books?id=fndPsRv08R0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=arithmetica+integra&hl=en&ei=CJVeTozEMonV0QGQ_LH9AQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false"
}

@inbook{Leiss,
    author    = "Ernst L. Leiss",
    title     = "A Programmer's Companion to Algorithm Analysis",
    year      = "2006",
    publisher     = "CRC Press",
    pages     = "28",
    ISBN     = "9781584886730"
}

@inbook{Rowan,
    author    = "Rowan Garnier and John Taylor",
    title     = "Discrete Mathematics, Proofs, Structures, and Applications",
    version     = "3",
    year      = "2009",
    publisher     = "CRC Press",
    pages     = "620",
    ISBN     = "9781439812808"
}

@inbook{Goodrich,
    author    = "Michael T. Goodrich and Roberto Tamassia",
    title     = "Algorithm Design: Foundations, Analysis, and Internet Examples",
    year      = "2002",
    publisher     = "John Wiley \& Sons",
    pages     = "23",
}

@inbook{Knuth,
    author    = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title     = "Fundamental Algorithms, The Art of Computer Programming",
    version     = "3",
    year      = "1997",
    publisher     = "Addison-Wesley Professional",
    pages     = "11",
    ISBN      = "9780321635747"
}

@inbook{Fred,
    author    = "Fred Roberts and Barry Tesman",
    title     = "Fundamental Algorithms, The Art of Computer Programming",
    version     = "2",
    year      = "2009",
    publisher     = "CRC Press",
    pages     = "206",
    ISBN      = "9781420099836"
}

@inbook{Steven,
    author    = "Steven S. Skiena",
    title     = "The Algorithm Design Manual",
    version     = "2",
    year      = "2009",
    publisher     = "Springer Press",
    address     = "New York",
    pages     = "78",
    ISBN      = "9781848000698"
}

@inbook{campbell,
  title={The Musician's Guide to Acoustics},
  author={Murray Campbell and Clive Greated},
  isbn={9780191591679},
  url={https://books.google.com/books?id=iiCZwwFG0x0C},
  year={1994},
  publisher={OUP Oxford}
}

@inbook{france,
  title={Introduction to Physical Education and Sport Science},
  author={Robert C. France},
  isbn={9781418055295},
  pages={282},
  lccn={2008930301},
  url={https://books.google.com/books?id=dH2nB1CX2SMC},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Cengage Learning}
}

@online{Eulernamed,
    author    = "Wikipedia",
    title     = "{List of things named after Leonhard Euler}",
    year    = "2007",
    url       = "{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Leonhard_Euler.html}"
}

@online{Powerset,
    author    = "Wikipedia",
    title     = "{Power set}",
    year    = "2015",
    url       = "{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set.html}"
}

@online{Comptree,
    author    = "Paul E. Black",
    title     = "{Complete Binary Tree}",
    year    = "2016",
    note       = {https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/completeBinaryTree.html}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\textsuperscript{[\@thefnmark]}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\textsuperscript{[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The Binary Logarithm ($\log_2  n$) is the power to which the number $2$ must be raised to obtain the value $n$ (for any real number $x$). Ergo, \[x = \log_2 n \Longleftrightarrow 2^x = n\] The first use of the binary logarithm was in music theory, by Leonhard Euler ~\footcite{Leonhard}, who is the only mathematician with two numbers named after him~\footcite{Eulernamed} (Euler's Number ($e \approx 2.71828$ ~\footcite{Eulernamed}) and the Euler-Mascheroni constant ($\gamma \approx 0.57721$) ~\footcite{Lagarias}). However, the first known table of binary logarithms is credited to Michael Stifel \footcite{Stifel}. Stifel was also the first to use the term "exponent" and includes the $q^m \times q^n = q^{m+n}$ and $ \frac{q^m}{q^n} = q^{m-n}$ ~\footcite{Stifel} rules in his book \emph{Arithmetica Integra}. Today's form of the binary logarithm (which applies to any number, and not necessarily a power $n$ to base $2$ ($2^n$) was established by Euler in 1739, in a table of binary logarithms for integers $1$ to $8$, to 7 decimal digits of accuracy\footcite{Leonhard}. has long been of use with computations, as $2^n$ is commonly used for the classification of $1$s and $0$s, mainly as Boolean values.

\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu

\printbibliography
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think arara has to do with the error. Probably the `biblatex` version you have on ubuntu is older than the Windows one.

Comment: @Arzigoglu I installed bibtex with TeXLive-Full 2016, shouldn't it be newer than my windows on (MiKTeX 2015)?

Comment: You will need to look at exact version numbers. I don't think there is anything called miktex 2015, latest version is 2.9. Also if you are using the Ubuntu texlive it is probably not 100% up to date, as latex from Linux distributions tend to be behind.

Comment: @daleif My version of BiBTex seems to be the newest one, the same as in MiKTeX 2.9, so I don't think it could be that

Comment: Bibtex has been unchanged for year, it is the biblatex versions you need to look at, try adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and the look in the full log file, at the end there will be a list of all packages and their versions

Comment: @daleif Adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` doesn't add any new information to the log file. It just ends when it gets to the error.

Comment: It compiles fine on my Linux using TeXLIve 2016 frozen. Try removing all aux-like files and recompile, then the list should be written.

Comment: Works fine here as well. I don't think you showed us the entire error though, what does the lines before that say? And re `\listfiles`, the additional information that gives is printed at the end of the log: Does `\listfiles \documentclass{article} \usepackage{biblatex} \begin{document} a \end{document}` work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I ran `% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara:pdflatex

\listfiles \documentclass{article} \usepackage{biblatex} \begin{document} a \end{document}`, which worked on its own in its own document

Comment: (Well, just `pdflatex` once would be enough.) So which version of `biblatex` is reported in the `.log` file? Also, did you try as @daleif suggested above, to first remove all the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl` etc.), and then compile again?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The `.log` file just returns [this](https://pastebin.com/nc5E6D1A), and there aren't any `.aux` or `.bbl` files. Does `.bib` count as one? Because deleting that didn't help.

Comment: You are not running the latest versions, by `biblatex` is from 2016/12/05 yours is from 2016/05/14. Please update your system, I even think this is a known error. Use `sudo tlmgr update --all --self` (assuming you installed as root) to update it.

Comment: @daleif that returns `TeX Live 2016 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated. ` Should this happen?

Comment: @TheBigFootsDad If you are using `biblatex`, why don't you simply use `% arara: biber`?

Comment: @samcarter The same error happens

Comment: @TheBigFootsDad this is normal, if there are updates (there should be since you are using a version older than mine), then it should start updating. The message just says that these are the final updates, and there will never be more updates for TeXLive 2016.

Comment: @daleif that didn't seem to work, the result is the same, in both the log file and the error message

Comment: Exactly which mirror is it taking data from?

Comment: @daleif How would I check that?

Comment: After the comment you mention, my tlmgr writes: `tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.uib.no/systems/texlive/tlnet `, there is a list of mirrors on the TUG.org website

Comment: @daleif The line I get it `tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.um.ac.ir/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)`